# Missing tar file in changes file after Debian package build

Tags: debian, packaging

I am back-porting the Debian package for openldap to jessie and have run into some problems with our local Debian repository. Using `git-buildpackage`, the Debian package goes fine, but when I get to the `dput` step I get an error. We have a local Debian repository where I am uploading this package. The local Debian repository uses reprepro.

The first part of the `dput` works, but the second part fails:

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Fri Feb 10 09:17:41 2017 PST using RSA key ID 53913E0C
gpg: Good signature from "Horace Linxster <hlinxster@example.com>"
Good signature on /srv/scratch/hlinxster/openldap/build-area/openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Fri Feb 10 09:17:28 2017 PST using RSA key ID 53913E0C
gpg: Good signature from " "Horace Linxster <hlinxster@example.com>"
Good signature on /srv/scratch/hlinxster/openldap/build-area/openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1.dsc.
Uploading to local (via scp to debian-local.example.com):
openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1.dsc                                                                      100% 2612     2.6KB/s   00:00    
openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1.debian.tar.xz                                                            100%  153KB 152.9KB/s   00:00    
slapd_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                                   100% 1401KB   1.4MB/s   00:00    
slapd-smbk5pwd_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                          100%   88KB  87.8KB/s   00:00    
ldap-utils_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                              100%  188KB 188.0KB/s   00:00    
libldap-2.4-2_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                           100%  218KB 218.5KB/s   00:00    
libldap-common_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_all.deb                                                            100%   83KB  82.6KB/s   00:00    
libldap-2.4-2-dbg_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                       100%  454KB 454.2KB/s   00:00    
libldap2-dev_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                            100%  324KB 323.8KB/s   00:00    
slapd-dbg_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb                                                               100% 4803KB   4.7MB/s   00:00    
openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.changes                                                            100% 4409     4.3KB/s   00:00    
Successfully uploaded packages.
file 'openldap_2.4.44+dfsg.orig.tar.gz' is needed for 'openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1.dsc', not yet registered in the pool and not found in 'openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1_amd64.changes'
There have been errors!
Error: post upload command failed.
```

It is true that `openldap_2.4.44+dfsg.orig.tar.gz` is not included in the `.changes` file; the only tar file listed in the `.changes` file is `openldap_2.4.44+dfsg-3.1.debian.tar.xz`. What do I need to do during the package build process to ensure that the tar file is listed in the `.changes` file properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `dpkg-genchanges` to include the original source, using its `-sa` option. You can give the option to `git-buildpackage` and it will pass it on:

```
gbp buildpackage -sa
```

(or `git-buildpackage -sa` perhaps with the Jessie version).

You only need to do that the first time you upload a given upstream version to a repository. If the version is "obviously" a new upstream (-1 or -0.1) then `dpkg-genchanges` figures it out on its own).

Comment: What will happen if you specify the `-sa` option and upload if the original source is *already* uploaded to the repository?

Comment: If the newly uploaded original source matches the previously uploaded source, the new upload should be accepted IIRC. If there's a mismatch it will be rejected.